# Switching back to Ubuntu 8.04.4 from 10.04.1

Tags: ubuntu, uninstall

I have done a big mistake of upgrading my system from `Ubuntu 8.04` to `10.04`. After the upgrade the system keeps on crashing now and then because of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/541492

`8.04.4 LTS` was just working great for me.

Does anyone know how to **downgrade** from Ubuntu 10.04 to 8.04 without losing any data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way :
Make a backup of data - Reinstall Ubuntu 8.04 - Restore data

You could also try with this guide to downgrade : 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DowngradeHowto